# solid obstacle in an JavaScript game

Tags: javascript

I am very new to coding. I am trying to make a game using java in notepad++. I cant seem to get it so that when the red square (player) hits the purple (TopEdge) the red square will not stop completely but also wont travel through the purple. Like a wall. Right now when the red square hits the purple, you cant move it anymore. I have tried almost everything i could find on the internet. Here is my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0"/>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
canvas {
    border:4px solid #000000;
    background-color: #1FB026;
}
</style>
</head>
<body onload="startGame()">
<script>

var player;
var TopEdge;

function startGame() {
player = new component(30, 30, "red", 10, 120);
TopEdge = new component(10000, 300, "purple", 0, -200);
myGameArea.start();
}
var myGameArea = {
    canvas : document.createElement("canvas"),
    start : function() {
        this.canvas.width = 1150;
        this.canvas.height = 500;
        this.context = this.canvas.getContext("2d");
        document.body.insertBefore(this.canvas,
        document.body.childNodes[0]);
        this.interval = setInterval(updateGameArea, 10);
    window.addEventListener('keydown', function (e) {
            myGameArea.keys = (myGameArea.keys || []);
            myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    window.addEventListener('keyup', function (e) {
      myGameArea.keys[e.keyCode] = (e.type == "keydown");
    })
    },
    clear : function(){
    this.context.clearRect(0, 0, this.canvas.width, this.canvas.height);
    },
    stop : function(){
      clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
}
function component(width, height, color, x, y) {
  this.width = width;
  this.height = height;
  this.speedX = 0;
  this.speedY = 0;
  this.x = x;
  this.y = y;
  this.update = function() {
  ctx = myGameArea.context;
  ctx.fillStyle = color;
  ctx.fillRect(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height);
}
    this.newPos = function() {
    this.X += this.speedX;
    this.Y += this.speedY;
let playerX = this.X + this.speedX;
let playerY = this.Y + this.speedY;
if (playerX >= 0 && this.width + playerX <= this.gamearea.canvas.width)
{
    this.X = playerX;
}
if (playerY >= 0 && this.height + playerY <= this.gamearea.canvas.height)
{
    this.Y = playerY;
}
    }
  this.crashWith = function(otherobj) {
    var myleft = this.x;
    var myright = this.x + (this.width);
    var mytop = this.y;
    var mybottom = this.y + (this.height);
    var otherleft = otherobj.x;
    var otherright = otherobj.x + (otherobj.width);
    var othertop = otherobj.y;
    var otherbottom = otherobj.y + (otherobj.height);
    var crash = true;
    if ((mybottom < othertop) ||
    (mytop > otherbottom) ||
    (myright < otherleft) ||
    (myleft > otherright)) {
      crash = false;
    }
    return crash;
  }
}
function stopY() {
    player.speedY = 0;
}
function updateGameArea() {
    if (player.crashWith(TopEdge)) {
    } else {
        myGameArea.clear();
        TopEdge.update();
        player.x += player.speedX;
        player.y += player.speedY;
        player.update();
    }
  TopEdge.update();
  player.speedX = 0;
  player.speedY = 0;
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[65]) {player.speedX = -2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[68]) {player.speedX = 2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[87]) {player.speedY = -2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys && myGameArea.keys[83]) {player.speedY = 2.5; }
  player.newPos();
  player.update();
  }
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The code is Javascript, not HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem starts with your updateGameArea() function.

If your the player crashes with the TopEdge then you do nothing. Your creating a problem with your else-part over there. It will never reach the else like this, so nothing while change, so next time it still won't move and again it will not reach the else.....

How about removing the else part. Just check for everything all the time, but don't allow it to move up when it reached the TopEdge.

This should help.

```
function updateGameArea() {
  // I'd prefer these calls at the end of the function block
  // but right now your program would start kinda buggy then
  myGameArea.clear();
  player.newPos();
  player.update();
  TopEdge.update();
  
  // In default state (nothing pressed) player shouldn't move up or down
  player.speedX = 0; 
  player.speedY = 0; 
  
  // If the player does press a key set correct speed/direction
  if (myGameArea.keys[65]) {player.speedX = -2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys[68]) {player.speedX = 2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys[87]) {player.speedY = -2.5; }
  if (myGameArea.keys[83]) {player.speedY = 2.5; }
   
  // Check if player reached the top
  // If it did, then it shouldn't be able to climb any higher.
  // So even if the player presses the up-button, 
  // the vertical speed should still not be aloud to change. 
  if (player.crashWith(TopEdge) && myGameArea.keys[87]) {
        player.speedY = 0;
  }
  
  // Move the position of the player
  player.x += player.speedX; //
  player.y += player.speedY;
  
}
```